# how to get the remaining qty per item using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem here that when I click copy row and I want to get the remaining qty per item, the result is not accurate.

So let's just say the item mouse has 100 qty, and I inputted new qty for 50. So the remaining should be 50. And when I copied the item mouse and inputted 40, so the remaining now is 10. Same goes for other items. This should be the expected output.

Current Situation

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/solomon099/9zL5nve7/44/)

```
$('.qty').on("keyup", function() {

        var id = $(this).data('id');
      var value = $(this).val();
      var sum = 0;
      $("#table_name .qty").filter(function(){ 
        if ($(this).data("id") == id){
          sum += parseFloat(value);
        }
      });
      console.log(sum);
      $('.remaining').val(sum);

  });
```

Comment: My dude edit your question with more info. What is your current output? What is expected? How are we to know what is "correct" to you? To my eyes, filling in a box named "Price" and expecting to update the quantity isn't "right"

Comment: My Bad. The price should be my new qty. So let's just say the item mouse has 100 qty, and I inputted new qty for 50. So the remaining should be 50. And when I copied the item mouse and inputted 40, so the remaining now is 10. Same goes for other items. This should be the expected output

Comment: @solomon would it be a umber of items from the total? E.G.: 100 Mouse, enter 40, hit Copy, new line appears with 40, and current line changes to 60?

Comment: That is correct my friend. It should have only 1 remaining for regardless of how many items you have copied. As long as it doesn't exceed the qty of item.

Comment: @Twisty any update?

Comment: The value for "remaining" seems to be the same across all rows, regardless of which row you modify, is this intentional?

Comment: Yes. That's my current problem.

Comment: @JonP Yes. That's my current problem

Comment: You have provided two different code versions, should we be working with what is on the jsfiddle or what is here on StackOverflow? Please edit your question to include *only* the relevant code.

Comment: @solomon Just for my own info haha why do you want to duplicate rows with identical values? If they should all update and remain the same etc why not just have one haha, just seems like poor design.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall logic is REALLY unclear. Here is an example that might help.

```js
$(function() {
  function refreshIndex($t) {
    $('tbody tr', $t).each(function(i, el) {
      var c = i + 1;
      var select = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(c);
    });
  }

  function copyRow(e) {
    var self = $(e.target);
    var row = self.closest("tr");
    row.clone().appendTo(self.closest("tbody"));
    refreshIndex($("#table_name"));
  }

  function updateItem(e) {
    var self = $(e.target);
    var row = self.closest("tr");
    var p = parseInt(self.val());
    var q = parseInt(row.find("td:eq(2) input").val());
    $('.remaining', row).val(q - p);
  }

  $("#table_name tbody").on("keyup", '.price', updateItem);
  $("#table_name tbody").on('click', '.copy', copyRow);

});
```

```css
#table_name tr td input {
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_name">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Qnty</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Remaing</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mouse</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="100" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" data-id="79"></td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-1">Copy</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="remaining"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Keyboard</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="20" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" data-id="80"></td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-2">Copy</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="remaining"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-3">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Monitor</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="50" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" data-id="81"></td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-3">Copy</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="remaining"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I enter `40` under Price, `60` appears as the difference between the Quantity and the Amount entered.

When Copy is clicked, a new row is appended, and functionality is binded to it already due to use of `.on()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But the remaining should not be per row. It should be per item. If there is 2 Monitor then their Total Qty should be the same. Like 2 monitors then I inputted qty's like (30 and 10) then the remaining qty of item monitor is only 10.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you can use the `data-id` attribute to target the rows you actually want to update.

```js
var clone_controll = function(num) {
  //Needed to mod this so add rows have the event handler
  $('#table_name').on("keyup", ".qty", function() {
  
    var id = $(this).data('id');
      var value = $(this).val();
      var sum = 0;
      
      
      //Filter is the wrong choice here - it is designed to filter objects
      /*$("#table_name .qty").filter(function(){ 
        if ($(this).data("id") == id){          
          //I think this logic is incorrect as well
          //You are only getting the value from the 
          //field you are typing in
          sum += parseFloat(value);
        }
      });*/
      
      /*Use a better selector with each()*/
      $("#table_name [data-id=" + id +"]").each(function(){
        //In this context "this" is the item iterated in "each"
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
        console.log(sum);
      });
      
      console.log("Final: " + sum);
      //Here is your problem, this updates All "remaining fields
      //$('.remaining').val(sum);
      
      //All rows contiaining this data id
      var relevantRows = $("[data-id=" + id + "]").closest("tr");
      //Update the "remaining fields in those rows
      $(relevantRows).find(".remaining").val(sum);
      
  });
}
clone_controll();

var $tableBody = $('#table_name').find("tbody");
clickEvent();
function clickEvent(){
  $tableBody.find('.copy').off('click').on('click',function() {
          $trLast = $(this).closest('tr'),
          $trNew = $trLast.clone();
          $trLast.after($trNew); 
          clickEvent();
          clone_controll();
  });
   function refresh_index(){
   $('#table_name > tbody > tr').each(function (i) {
      i++;
      var select = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(i);
    });
  }
  refresh_index();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_name">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Your Qty</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Remaing per item(not per row)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mouse</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="100" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" data-id="79"></td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-1">Copy</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="remaining"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Keyboard</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="20" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" data-id="80"></td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-2">Copy</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="remaining"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-3">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Monitor</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="50" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" data-id="81"></td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-3">Copy</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="remaining"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your logic is still pretty unclear, but hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction.